# jQuery.get() not populating div

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's wrong with this function:

```
function() {
    $.get('/controller/action', function(data) {
        $('#temporaryPhotos').text(data);
    } );
    return false;
}
```

What it should do is fetch HTML from */controller/action* page and insert the HTML into the `#temporaryPhotos` div on the current page.

Initial markup looks like this:

```
<div id="temporaryPhotos"></div>
```

So it's just an empty div. The jQuery function should fill it with photos form another page (it's the same website, of course). But the div stays empty.

### EDIT:

I think I have not been very clear with my post so here is an additional information. What I am actually trying to accomplish is to use the abovementioned function as a callback for the Uploadify jquery plugin (http://www.uploadify.com).

Here is the full javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#photo').uploadify({
        'uploader'       : '/flash-uploader/scripts/uploadify.swf',
        'script'         : '/flash-uploader/scripts/upload-public-photo.php',
        'cancelImg'      : '/flash-uploader/cancel.png',
        'scriptData'     : {'user_id' : 'USER_ID'},
        'queueID'        : 'fileQueue',
        'auto'           : true,
        'multi'          : true,
        'sizeLimit'      : 2097152,
        'fileExt'        : '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
        'wmode'          : 'transparent',
        'onComplete'     : function() {
            $.get('/controller/action', function(data) {
                alert(data);
                $('#temporaryPhotos').html(data);
            } );
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried both text() and html(), also alert(). Still nothing :(

### EDIT2:

Upon further research I have found out that a default onComplete() function in the Uploadify plugin looks like this:

```
jQuery(this).bind("uploadifyComplete", {'action': settings.onComplete}, function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
    if (event.data.action(event, ID, fileObj, unescape(response), data) !== false) {
        jQuery("#" + jQuery(this).attr('id') + ID + " .percentage").text(' - Completed');
        jQuery("#" + jQuery(this).attr('id') + ID).fadeOut(250, function() { jQuery(this).remove()});
    }
});
```

I have rewritten this function with my own (first one in this post) and that appears to be a problem.

### EDIT3:

Head section of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/flash-uploader/scripts/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/flash-uploader/scripts/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#photo').uploadify({
        'uploader'       : '/flash-uploader/scripts/uploadify.swf',
        'script'         : '/flash-uploader/scripts/upload-public-photo.php',
        'cancelImg'      : '/flash-uploader/cancel.png',
        'scriptData'     : {'user_id' : 1},
        'queueID'        : 'fileQueue',
        'auto'           : true,
        'multi'          : true,
        'sizeLimit'      : 2097152,
        'fileExt'        : '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
        'wmode'          : 'transparent',
        'onComplete'     : function() {
            alert("hello");
        }
    });
});    //]]>
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/document-ready.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [html](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html) instead of text:

```
 $('#temporaryPhotos').html(data);
```

Also, you might want to try alerting the response to see what's coming back from the server:

```
function() {
    $.get('/controller/action', function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $('#temporaryPhotos').html(data);
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Exactly. Just clarifying, using text you are inserting the `data` argument inside `#temporaryPhotos` as a textNode, so escaping is automatically done by the browser.

Comment: @Spidey - correct, opening "<" and closing ">" tags are replaced by their respective entities.

Comment: @Richard Knop - if you run the $.get part alone, will something get returned from the server? First try to establish if the back-end is returning something or not.

Comment: Yes. I tried putting the $.get function on click() event on a link on the page, and then I do alert(data) and it returns correct content.

Comment: @Richard Knop - try replacing the 'onComplete' callback with this simple function: function() { alert('hello'); } and see if that fires

Comment: @Richard Knop - so we've isolated the problem to uploadify. Now for a really annoying question, have you included the uploadify.js *after* jQuery? Is it getting loaded in properly?

Comment: Yes it is. I have posted excerpt from the head section of the page in the first post.

Comment: Yes it is loading properly because other features of the Uploadify are working fine, files are getting uploading ok, the backend PHP script is being executed etc...

Comment: @Richard Knop - can you try including swfobject.js after jquery.uploadify.v2.1.0.min.js", see what happens (remember to keep the alert('hello') in place). This is turning out to be a real pain, but with a bit of luck everything will work out.

Comment: Ok I have solved the problem. The problem was at the end of the PHP backend file there must be line echo "1"; so the plugin knows when the uploading process is finished :);

Comment: @Richard Knop - LOL! Feel better now?

Comment: Yeah, such stupid mistake. It's not mentioned in the plugin documentation :D

Answer (score 1):

.text(str) inserts the str as plaintext (escaping the tags)

```
$("p").text("<b>Some</b> new text.");

<b>Some</b> new text.
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text#val

.html(str) inserts it as html.

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint in firebug to make sure you aren't misusing Uploadify.